# Using a local install of phantomjs for "ember test"

Tags: ember.js

From a continuous integration perspective, I would prefer to use a local install instead of a global one as the docs currently state. I've searched for a while and looked at the api from "ember test --help" and I don't see the ability to explicitly state the location of phantomjs - ember expects it to be available globally.

Is it possible to run something like "ember test --phantomjs node_modules\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs"? Or modify testem.js to state phantomjs location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run tests with `npm test` in such case `node_modules/.bin` added into path for commands which are inside script section in `package.json`

So thus in package.json you have

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test",
```

`npm test` will run `ember test` but for that running it will add `node_modules/.bin` into PATH. So you can keep phantom in local dependencies